# Setting array in pseudocode

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

If I have an array A of n elements and want to set the elements 1 to m to zero, how should I write this in pseudocode?
We all know, depending how "primitive" your real programming language is, you may have to write a for-loop for that.

Would it be ok to write

```
A[1, ..., m] <- 0
```

Seems a bit confusing...
any compact alternatives (no for-loop)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's pseudocode, which means there are no rules and you can write whatever makes your intent clear to your readers. What you have written seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Pseudo code can be absolutely anything, provided it is consistent and clear. Where it isn't clear, write a legend to show the reader how to interpret the pseudo code.

Comment: I think pseudo code gives you a lot of artistic license :-) I guess whatever is readable to your audience will work...

Comment: If I can't describe it in symbols, I just spell it out in words for clarity. Otherwise there's no point in writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We all agree that your pseudocode looks ok, but I also agree it doesn't describe everything you told with words, as n can be greater than m for example, right? What I thought about when I read your question was doing something like this:

```
A <- zeros(A,m) // zeros(arry,n) returns the same array 'arry' but with 0s in the entries from 1 to n
```

As it's pseudocode, just making a comment next to the assignment with a brief description of the invented function  should be ok to me I guess.

Hope it helped!